# jQuery Class is not add in mobile view browser

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am adding on class on button click even like this

`$('#someid').addclass("active11");`

when i view in browser at that time this class added successfully but when i view in restore button(means mobile view) at that time that added class is not show.

How can achieve this ? Plz help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it should be addClass, with capital C.

this is the correct syntax:

```
$( "element" ).addClass( "myClass" );
```